# How to compare two lists and get the indices of new values

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find the index of a new name in the list.
I've found the new renters name, but for some reason the index function is not working.

```
new = ["Maria", "Eric", "Bram", 'Bernardo', 'Bob']
old = ['Karel', 'Maria', 'Eric', 'Bram', 'Bernardo']

newrenter = list(set(new) - set(old))

print(newrenter)

newindex = new.index(newrenter)

print(newindex)
```

Which outputs:

```py
['Bob']
```

Then the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 8>()
      4 newrenter = list(set(new) - set(old))
      6 print(newrenter)
----> 8 newindex = new.index(newrenter)
     10 print(newindex)

ValueError: ['Bob'] is not in list
```

It is probably an easy conversion of the type but I cant find how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`newrenter` is `['Bob']` and as you can see `'bob'` is in your list not `['bob']`.
your code expects a list in another list. but `'new'` only contains string elements.

I can not see your expectation of using `.index()`. but I imagine this will helps you:

```
newindex = new.index(newrenter[0])
```

And if you need all of remaining items indexes, try this:

```
new = ["Maria", 'Martin', "Eric", "Bram", 'Bernardo', 'Bob']  # I add Martin for better clue
old = ['Karel', 'Maria', 'Eric', 'Bram', 'Bernardo']

newrenter = list(set(new) - set(old))

for v in newrenter:
    print("value:", v, end=" - ")
    print("index in new:", new.index(v))
```

This code will return:

```
value: Bob - index in new: 5
value: Martin - index in new: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close with the attempt, this will work:

```py
    new = ["Maria", "Eric", "Bram", 'Bernardo', 'Bob']
    old = ['Karel', 'Maria', 'Eric', 'Bram', 'Bernardo']
    
    l = list(set(new) - set(old))
    
    for x in l:
        print(new.index(x))
```

this is the result:

```
4
```